# swagger-document-override/md-override-loader - FAILED

Tags: .net-core, swashbuckle, autorest

I am able to generate code using Autorest with my api when I host it on a server 2012R2 running IIS

However when I try to run it with the localhost url I get a could not read message.

I can read swagger.json in the browser

I am using the command

```
autorest --input-file=https://localhost:44348/api-docs/v1/swagger.json
--output-folder=generated --csharp --namespace=DD.MyApp.Connector
```

The output is

```
AutoRest code generation utility [version: 2.0.4283; node: v10.11.0]
(C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation.
https://aka.ms/autorest
   Loading AutoRest core      'C:\Users\kirst\.autorest\@microsoft.azure_autorest-core@2.0.4289\node_modules\@microsoft.azure\autorest-core\dist' (2.0.4289)
   Loading AutoRest extension '@microsoft.azure/autorest.csharp' (~2.3.79->2.3.82)
   Loading AutoRest extension '@microsoft.azure/autorest.modeler' (2.3.55->2.3.55)
FATAL: swagger-document-override/md-override-loader - FAILED
FATAL: Error: Could not read 'https://localhost:44348/api-docs/v1/swagger.json'.
FATAL: swagger-document/loader - FAILED
FATAL: Error: Could not read 'https://localhost:44348/api-docs/v1/swagger.json'.
Process() cancelled due to exception : Could not read 'https://localhost:44348/api-docs/v1/swagger.json'.
  Error: Could not read 'https://localhost:44348/api-docs/v1/swagger.json'.
```

After studying [the issue on github](https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/2670) I tried starting the api using dotnet run 
but it did not help.

I tried running autorest in a dos command shell with admin priviledge

As per the github issue I can save the swagger.json to a file and generate the code by referencing the file.

That isn't a great solution.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/2670

Comment: I aren't experiencing this problem any more. I wonder if it has anything to do with a Visual Studio version.

Answer (score 2):

Are you attempting to use `https` with `localhost` ? If you haven't put a certificate on there, you shouldn't be using `https`.

Try it with `http://localhost`...

Comment: it works fine with https ( as I say, it is working now)  I have Enable SSL checked in the Debug tab of the solution.